# Error XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, java, popup

I have a ORG production where a link open a POPUP code works, but the same code in sandbox does not.

Error:
[image]

In console chrome:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

The sandbox is the same code production.
The jquery path works and is correct.

Code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/js/functions.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQuery/ui/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQuery/postmessage/jquery.ba-postmessage.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQuery/bbq/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js')} 

var statusAcc = "{!Account.Status__c}"; 
var abrirTela = false; 
if(statusAcc != "A cadastramentar"){ 
abrirTela = true; 
}else{ 
abrirTela = confirm('Esta conta já foi enviada. Você tem certeza que deseja editá-la?'); 
} 
if(abrirTela){ 

function requireCssFile(filename) { 
var fileref = document.createElement('link'); 
fileref.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet'); 
fileref.setAttribute('type', 'text/css'); 
fileref.setAttribute('href', filename); 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref); 
} 

requireCssFile('/resource/jQuery/ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css'); 

var j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); 

var canal = "{!Account.Canal__c}"; 
var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/Informacao?id=" + Account.Id + "&Canal=")}' + canal; 


var largura = 800; 
var altura = 525; 

var child_domain = iframe_url.substring(0, iframe_url.indexOf('/', 9)); 
var parent_domain = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host; 

j$.receiveMessage( 
function(e){ 
var cross_result = j$.deparam(e.data); 
if(j$.browser.msie){ 
document.body.scroll = "yes"; 
document.documentElement.style.overflowX = 'visible'; 
document.documentElement.style.overflowY = 'visible'; 
}else{ 
document.onmousewheel = true; 
document.onkeydown = true; 
} 

if (cross_result.action == 'close_modal_dialog') { 
j$modalDialog.dialog('close'); 
} else { 
j$modalDialog.dialog('close'); 
j$(location).attr('href', cross_result.redirect_url); 
} 
}, 
child_domain 
); 

var j$modalDialog = j$('<div></div>') 
.html('<iframe id="iframeContentId" src="' + iframe_url + '&parent_domain=' + parent_domain + '" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="yes"/>') 
.dialog({ 
autoOpen: false, 
title: 'Informação', 
resizable: false, 
width: largura, 
height: altura, 
autoResize: true, 
modal: true, 
draggable: false, 
closeOnEscape: false, 
open: function(event, ui) { j$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); } 
}); 

var ieVersao = parseInt(j$.browser.version, 10); 
if(j$.browser.msie){ 
document.body.scroll = "no"; 
document.documentElement.style.overflowX = 'hidden'; 
document.documentElement.style.overflowY = 'hidden'; 
}else{ 
document.onmousewheel=function(){return false}; 
document.onkeydown=function(){return event.keyCode==38 || event.keyCode==40 ? false : true;} 
} 

j$modalDialog.dialog('open'); 

}
```

I looked permissions and are equal.
Any idea?